# Error - any Cordova command

Tags: cordova

When I try any Cordova command, returns this message:

> ? May Cordova anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time? (Y/n) events.js:161
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ Error: read EINVAL
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1023:11)
>       at TTY.onread (net.js:572:26)

I'm using Node.js v7.5.0 in Windows 7.

I tried to uninstall e install Cordova again, but the same error appears in any command.

Command example:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

I can't put y/n for the question, just appear, but isn't possible put an option. The error occurs immediately after the command.

How fix?

Tks

Comment: Are you responding with a (y/n) option? Is that "events.js:throw..." happening after you give an answer, or in one big lump?

Comment: Also, are you connected to the internet while doing this?

Comment: I can't put y/n, just appear, but isn't possible put an option.

Comment: Yes, I'm connected. But I have a corporate proxy configured in Node.js.

Comment: Try a command using the `--verbose` flag at the end. It should give you more details about the error.

Comment: The same error appears. I tried: cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld --verbose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question you are getting is the telemetry option. It is only supposed to last 30 seconds the first time you run Cordova. Clearly yours has an error. Try manually setting it with the CLI:

```
cordova telemetry off               // or on
```